# android telephony (api 17/ android 4.2) issues

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to use the new [telephony API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo.html). I make a call to TelephonyManager's [getAllCellInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo%28%29) but all I ever get back is a null object (meaning its unavailable).

Currently using a nexus 4 with the official rom with the latest update (4.2.2).

Should add:

- I'm not getting any errors from the DDMS.
- I do have ACCESS_COURSE_UPDATES in my manifest

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That function requires some permissions set, particularly ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES, make sure you add this to your application manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
```

In addition the telephony api regarding reading phone states will probably need this also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I do have ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES. I don't have READ_PHONE_STATE enabled but I'm not using any of that. added it and it made no difference. Thanks though

Comment: Just to check, your phone has a valid sim card inside and is connected to a network? Not in flight mode or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i gave up the class CellInfo, but used CellLocation to get information.